# How to overwrite/customize my woo-commerce child theme over the parent theme?

Tags: php, woocommerce, parent-child

I had tried to do some modification for my child theme for woo-commerce checkout-page and it seems i followed different steps to proceed the modification it doesn't work. So what happen is I when to my child theme and created a directory named "woocommerce" and inside I placed the "form-checkoutpage.php". I had followed the instruction from this [link](https://www.dreamhost.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-woocommerce-child-theme/) but it doesn't work on me. Is there something I miss out?

Comment: `doesn't work` is very broad...

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information in your post for anybody to help you. Please read your question as if you are someone who has no idea what you're working on, have a bit of a think, and edit your question with actual information.

Comment: Hi, I had changed the description. Sorry for the lack of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things.

1. There is no woo template called **form-checkoutpage.php** but there is one called **form-checkout.php**. Make sure it has the exact correct file name.
2. Its location has to match the same directory structure as shown in the woo templates directory, so in this case it needs to be **your-theme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php**

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your advise and I had sort that out. Cheers.